# JavaScript cannot parse into Number

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I'm trying to make the total change based on the search criteria that I have on the FORM AREA. However, for some reason it doesn't parse the string into an array and the total is not displayed properly it has something like e+88 at the end. Totally a newbie at this.

```js
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    var month = $('#inputMonth').val(); // get option value for month
    if (month == 'none') month = '';
    var year = $('#inputYear').val(); // get option value for year
    if (year == 'none') year = '';
    var arr = [];
    var totalPrice = 0;
    var price;
    
    // problematic part
    $('figure.col-sm-3').has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + year + ')').has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + month + ')').each(function () {
        arr.push($('tr.price td:nth-child(even)').text()); // adds each element to array 'arr'
        price = $('tr.price td:nth-child(even)').text();
        totalPrice += Number(price); // parse into an Integer then do the adding
        document.getElementById("displayTotal").innerHTML = "Total amount is currently at <b>"+totalPrice+ "</b> PHP."; // problematic part.
    });
    
    // this snippet works fine
    $('figure.col-sm-3')
        .hide() // hide all of them, and then show if both `has` are true
        .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + year + ')')
        .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + month + ')')
        .show();
        
    return false; // to avoid that button submits the form
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- FORM AREA -->
        <p id="displayTotal"></p> <!-- display the total here -->
        <p>Show items by:</p>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMonth" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Month</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputMonth">
                        <option value="none"> - </option>
                        <option value="January">January</option>
                        <option value="February">February</option>
                        <option value="March">March</option>
                        <option value="April">April</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="June">June</option>
                        <option value="July">July</option>
                        <option value="August">August</option>
                        <option value="September">September</option>
                        <option value="October">October</option>
                        <option value="November">November</option>
                        <option value="December">December</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputYear" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Year</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputYear">
                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Show results</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- FIRST SET OF ITEMS -->
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 1</h6>
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>November 7, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 2</h6>
            <img src="img2.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>December 2, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 3</h6>
            <img src="img3.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>L</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 4</h6>
            <img src="img4.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>XL</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try to do `totalPrice += parseFloat(price)`

Comment: Try  parseInt() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: e+88 It means 10 to the power 88.

Comment: This "arr.push($('tr.price td:nth-child(even)').text());" is adding things like this into the array: "250250250250".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you were accessing all elements with that class rather than those scoped to the current element in the iteration. You were therefore getting the price repeated over and over. I have a amended the code and removed the mixed vanilla javascript to keep things uniform. I have also moved the setting of the total price text outside of the loop to stop needlessly setting it over and over again. Code:

```
$('figure.col-sm-3').has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + year + ')').has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + month + ')').each(function(index, self) {
            var price = $(self).find("tr.price td:nth-child(even)").eq(0).text()
        arr.push(price);
        totalPrice += parseFloat( price );
    });
    $("#displayTotal").html("Total amount is currently at <b>" + totalPrice + "</b> PHP.");
```

Comment: Nicolas Henneaux's answer worked too but if the results showed no items, the result wouldn't update to reflect the each items' prices. This answer filled that gap up. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From the problematic part to the end of the problematic part, try this instead:

```
// Comment in JavaScript are prefixed by //
$('figure.col-sm-3').each(function(e) {
    var soldOn = e.children('tr').last().children('td').last().val();

    if ($soldOn.indexOf(year) >= 0 && $soldOn.indexOf(month)) {
        var price = e.children('tr.price').first().children('td').last().val();

        arr.push(price); // Adds each element to array 'arr'
        totalPrice += price;

        document.getElementById("displayTotal").innerHTML = "Total amount is currently at <b>"+totalPrice+ "</b> PHP.";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over elements instead of parsing the text value of the array of elements.

```js
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    var month = $('#inputMonth').val(); // get option value for month
    if (month == 'none') month = '';
    var year = $('#inputYear').val(); // get option value for year
    if (year == 'none') year = '';
    var arr = [];
    var totalPrice = 0.00;
    var price;
    
    // problematic part
document.getElementById("displayTotal").innerHTML = "Total amount is currently at <b>"+totalPrice+ "</b> PHP.";

    $('figure.col-sm-3').has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + year + ')').has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + month + ')').each(function (_index, element) {
$(element).find('tr.price td:nth-child(even)').each(function(_i, element){
    totalPrice += parseFloat(element.textContent);
    });
         // parse into an Integer then do the adding
        document.getElementById("displayTotal").innerHTML = "Total amount is currently at <b>"+totalPrice+ "</b> PHP."; // problematic part.
    });
    
    // this snippet works fine
    $('figure.col-sm-3')
        .hide() // hide all of them, and then show if both `has` are true
        .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + year + ')')
        .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + month + ')')
        .show();
        
    return false; // to avoid that button submits the form
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- FORM AREA -->
        <p id="displayTotal"></p> <!-- display the total here -->
        <p>Show items by:</p>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMonth" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Month</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputMonth">
                        <option value="none"> - </option>
                        <option value="January">January</option>
                        <option value="February">February</option>
                        <option value="March">March</option>
                        <option value="April">April</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="June">June</option>
                        <option value="July">July</option>
                        <option value="August">August</option>
                        <option value="September">September</option>
                        <option value="October">October</option>
                        <option value="November">November</option>
                        <option value="December">December</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputYear" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Year</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputYear">
                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Show results</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- FIRST SET OF ITEMS -->
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 1</h6>
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>November 7, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 2</h6>
            <img src="img2.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>December 2, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 3</h6>
            <img src="img3.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>L</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 4</h6>
            <img src="img4.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>XL</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `parseInt` or `parseFloat`. Better choice is `parseInt`

```
totalPrice += parseInt(price)
```

**OR**

```
totalPrice += parseFloat(price)
```

Finish by rounding the final total to a suitable decimal precision (2 makes sense in most cases regarding currency!)

```
totalPrice = totalPrice.toFixed(2) /* only in case of parseFloat */
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't have used `toFixed(0)` per increment. It makes more sense to round up the total value to 2 decimal places once the total has been fully incremented rather than rounded per loop

Comment: Just a guess... A) This answer is in the comments, 6 minutes before you answered. B) This doesn't answer the question - he gets an error parsing an integer, but clearly his code is the problem - not that he doesn't know how to parse an integer. If you say to me "a bridge is falling down, two of the big screws fell out!" and you asked for my help and I said "you can hammer a nail using a hammer", that's not a solution to the problem, that's pointing out the obvious on how to hammer a nail into something.

Comment: Yeah, you can change the decimal value as per your requirement. My concern with `toFixed` was only to let you remember that `parseInt` will not give any decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total= Array.from(
                $('figure').filter((i,e)=>{
                  var html=$(e).find('tr:eq(3) td:eq(1)').html();
                  return html.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#inputMonth').val().toLowerCase())>=0 &&  html.indexOf($('#inputYear').val())>=0

                })
           ).map((e)=>parseInt($(e).find('tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').html())
           ).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/DTcHh/23329/)

### Don't make mistakes in Selector , MEANS , Get the expected result